# Generate poll/survey code from ordered list of answers to be used in email newsletter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem where I need to generate a poll/survey template from a list of answers to be used in an email newsletter.

So
- The poll is created in the CMS and answers are displayed in an ordered list. There's a text field in the list item where users input their answer.
- Beneath the ordered list is a textarea with a button called "generate poll code" right beneath it
- On clicking the button, javascript should generate the desired "template" with the Answers, Answer Ids and the Poll Id in anchor links with a query (as shown below).

So the ordered list markup is as following:

```
<ol id="9999">
    <li id="1234"><input value="Answer1"/></li>
    <li id="5678"><input value="Answer1"/></li>
    <li id="9876"><input value="Answer1"/></li>
</ol>
```

Where the poll ID is the id of the ordered list and each li has the answer ID.

What I've been trying to get is this simple list of anchor links:

```
Poll question<br />
<a href="http://urlpath?pollId=9999&answerId="1234">Answer 1</a>
<a href="http://urlpath?pollId=9999&answerId="5678">Answer 1</a>
<a href="http://urlpath?pollId=9999&answerId="9876">Answer 1</a>
```

So basically, on click, iterate over the ordered list, grab the ids and then output the anchor list with the ids in the right places.

Just reduce this email, I haven't included my unsuccessful attempts at this, where I tried to use a for loop, get the Ids, store them in an array and then build the anchor link template with those injected.

Is there anyone who knows of good way to handle this and get the desired results

Very grateful for any assistance, THANK YOU!

- L

Comment: __You should not use GET for this kind of thing__ – email providers like Google, Microsoft etc. who are also in the search engine business will most likely extract those URLs from the emails you send, and have their spiders visit them – which fill falsify your results, since no _real_ user actually _answered_ your question. (Using POST by having forms _in your email_ will most likely not work either in many email clients – so your best option is to link to a web page from your email that the user can visit and vote there [again, use POST there, otherwise you will have the same problem again].)

Comment: Thanks CBroe! Appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over each list item using .each and output the html for each item.

```
    //use .each to loop over each li
    $('#9999 li').each(function(){
        //for each li, get its id and val
        var li_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var inp_val = $(this).find('input').val();
        //append it somewhere and drop values in
        $('#output').append('<a href="http://urlpath?pollId=9999&answerId=' + li_id + '">' + inp_val + '</a><br>' );
    });
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/omgo/fThq9/2/

Comment: Hey omgo, that's just what I'm after, thanks for taking the time to answer that. I forgot to mention though in the example that I need to add that as the value of a textarea so the users can copy/paste the code to use in a newsletter. When I changed it to add to the val() of the textarea, it only grabbed one of the anchor links, do you know how to go around that by any chance ? Thanks again for your help, much appreciated!